# Not got the Suffrage badge on SO (or SU) despite hitting the vote limit

Tags: support, badges, voting

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68024/i-was-just-awarded-the-suffrage-badge-without-proper-cause), but the opposite problem.

I know that I've hit the vote limit several times on Stack Overflow and Super User, yet I haven't been awarded the Suffrage badge.

The only thing I can think of is that at least one of the posts I voted for on those days have been deleted, thus meaning that there is only at most 29 votes recorded by me on those days.

Can someone confirm if that's the case?

**NOTE:** I decided to spend some time voting on SO and SU so it could well be that by the time you read this I have the badge - but I'll leave the question open for others.

Comment: I figured the same - I only hit the cap a few days, and posts were probably deleted. That is a common problem with new badges - they aren't really retroactive. For example, I may have qualified for `Tenacious` at some point, but it is impossible to get it now.

Comment: @Kobi - me too on `Tenacious` and `Unsung Hero`. It will mean that I have to up my voting again - which is a good thing anyway.

Comment: I've posted a feature request for this, I'd like something similar to the reputation report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68032/how-do-i-audit-my-votes

Comment: I can see zero evidence of any problems with this badge.. every time we audit, it is correct. Shrug.

Comment: @Jeff - I'm not saying that *as run now* on my vote *history* it can't find a day when I used all my votes up, but I find it odd as I **do** remember using them all up on several occasions. It must be due to deleted posts. It would be nice to have that confirmed though.

Comment: @Jeff, I know I should have got one on SuperUser, but didn't.  Are deleted/migrated posts why?

Comment: "I decided to spend some time voting on SO and SU". You've fallen for their ploy :)

Answer (score 3):

It could be that a lot of your votes were for post by the same user, and the system decided to delete those votes.  This can happen when you look at a user with the same interests as you and then read a lot of their quesions/answers upvoting the ones you find helpful.

Comment: I'm aware of the vote fraud algorithms and try to avoid voting patterns that would trigger them. I don't "follow" users that way.