# How do I audit my votes?

Tags: feature-request, voting

Can we have a report of our votes, similar to [stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) ?
The reputation report only shows negative votes that lost reputation, can we see a report of all votes?

> Related:
>
> - [I was just awarded the Suffrage badge without proper cause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68024/7586)
> - [Not got the Suffrage badge on SO (or SU) despite hitting the vote limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68029/7586)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out how many of my votes are for questions rather than answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38941/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-of-my-votes-are-for-questions-rather-than-answers)

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned

Comment: @Ian - Thanks. I think this isn't really a duplicate, but my feature request will solve all of these issues, and should be easy to implement. To be clear, I'm talking about a full dump of all votes with date question/answer id, not a counter.

Comment: I wonder if giving out reputation for participating in US elections would help get that system this level of scrutiny.  Though for some reason people aren't as excited about the 'I voted' stickers.